# Get total number of likes for each user in an array of objects - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm stuck with a logical problem. I'm trying to figure out a way of getting total number of likes for each user in an array of objects. Here is my Sample array.

```
const articles = [{
  authorId: "2vP3i2rYvDYPrikE1k1DTaZDeoq1",
  dislikes: 0,
  likes: 3,
  neutral: 0,
  text: "This is Mike Alice's first Shot!!",
  username: "mikealice",
  id: "NMFGbeTvSYddsr7VzjFV",
},
 {
  authorId: "2vP3i2rYvDYPrikE1k1DTaZDeoq1",
  dislikes: 0,
  likes: 2,
  neutral: 0,
  text: "This is Mike Alice's second Shot!!",
  username: "mikealice",
  id: "NMFGbeTvSYddsr7VzjFV",
},
 {
  authorId: "2vP3i2rYvDYPrikE1k1klkDTaZDeoq1",
  dislikes: 0,
  likes: 1,
  neutral: 0,
  text: "This is admin's first Shot!!",
  username: "admin",
  id: "NMFGbeTvSYddsr7VzjFV",
},
 {
  authorId: "2vP3i2rYvDYPrikE1k1klkDTaZDeoq1",
  dislikes: 0,
  likes: 3,
  neutral: 0,
  text: "This is admin's second Shot!!",
  username: "admin",
  id: "NMFGbeTvSYddsr7VzjFV",
}]
```

My goal is to have a final list of of distinct username with their total likes like the one bellow.

```
const userLikes = [
  {
  username: 'mikealice',
  totalLikes: 5
  },
  {
  username: 'admin',
  totalLikes: 4
  }
]
```

Help me figure out the logic to solving this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: So far, I've not been able to figure out the easiest way to solve it. My initial thinking was looping through the array and creating another array where each object has a username and the likes.  Something like this. ```articles.forEach((article) => {
  userArticles.push( { username: article.username, likes: article.likes})
})``` and now I need to find distinct username and add up the likes but that is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `reduce` and `Object.values` will simplify.

```js
const getTotalLikes = arr =>
  Object.values(
    arr.reduce((acc, { username, likes }) => {
      acc[username] =
        username in acc
          ? { username, totalLikes: acc[username].totalLikes + likes }
          : { username, totalLikes: likes };
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );

const articles = [
  {
    authorId: "2vP3i2rYvDYPrikE1k1DTaZDeoq1",
    dislikes: 0,
    likes: 3,
    neutral: 0,
    text: "This is Mike Alice's first Shot!!",
    username: "mikealice",
    id: "NMFGbeTvSYddsr7VzjFV"
  },
  {
    authorId: "2vP3i2rYvDYPrikE1k1DTaZDeoq1",
    dislikes: 0,
    likes: 2,
    neutral: 0,
    text: "This is Mike Alice's second Shot!!",
    username: "mikealice",
    id: "NMFGbeTvSYddsr7VzjFV"
  },
  {
    authorId: "2vP3i2rYvDYPrikE1k1klkDTaZDeoq1",
    dislikes: 0,
    likes: 1,
    neutral: 0,
    text: "This is admin's first Shot!!",
    username: "admin",
    id: "NMFGbeTvSYddsr7VzjFV"
  },
  {
    authorId: "2vP3i2rYvDYPrikE1k1klkDTaZDeoq1",
    dislikes: 0,
    likes: 3,
    neutral: 0,
    text: "This is admin's second Shot!!",
    username: "admin",
    id: "NMFGbeTvSYddsr7VzjFV"
  }
];

console.log(getTotalLikes(articles));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Take an empty object, say `obj`
2. Loop through your `array`
3. On every loop, check for if `obj` has already a key same as the current `username`
4. If not then, create a key value pair, key would be the `username`, value would be another `object` containing `username` and `totalLikes`
5. If there is already a key same as `username`, increase the value of `totalLikes` with current `likes`
6. After the loop is finished, you will have your answer, but in a `dictionary`/`object` form
7. `Object.values` will bring out the desired `array`

Code -

```js
let obj = {}

articles.forEach((article, index) => {
  let { username, likes } = article

  if (!obj[username]) {
  
    obj[username] = {
      username,
      totalLikes: likes
    }
    
  } 

  else {
 
    let { totalLikes } = obj[username]
    obj[username].totalLikes = totalLikes + likes
    
  }

})

let finalArray = Object.values(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sajjad. This is a great explanation of how to approach the problem.